# How to wrap occurences of string in containers in python

Tags: python, html, string

I have an application that renders HTML and I wish to add a find function that will wrap any matches in span tags so that I can style them.

```
html = """

<html>
    <h1>hello world</h1>
    <p>This is text to display</p>
</html>

"""

match = "h"
```

the string in the match variable should be any length.

**Note:** I don't want to match any "h" characters that appear in tags.

I am willing to use Beautiful Soup or other libraries.

my HTML:

```
    <html>
 <h1>
  Kraken-MD
 </h1>
 <br/>
 <hr/>
 <br/>
 View markdown on your computer with ease, launch Kraken MD from command line or open a file!
 <br/>
 <blockquote>
  <span style="color: grey; background-color: grey;">
   |
  </span>
  <b>
   Note:
  </b>
  Only basic markdown capability is present, if you wish to render more advanced markdown, download another renderer, this program is a work in progress and is
  <i>
   not
  </i>
  yet fully capable. Updates are being worked on.
 </blockquote>
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <i>
  Kraken MD
 </i>
 is a markdown renderer for the Windows operating system. Its purpose is to display formatted markdown.
 <br/>
 <br/>
 To begin, open Kraken MD and go to
 <span style="color: maroon;">
  <code>
   File &gt; Open
  </code>
 </span>
 or press CTRL+O and select a
 <span style="color: maroon;">
  <code>
   .md
  </code>
 </span>
 file. Your file will be displayed in the window.
 <br/>
 <br/>
 You can also open a file immediately via the command line. Simply enter
 <span style="color: maroon;">
  <code>
   python index.py
   <filepath>
   </filepath>
  </code>
 </span>
 where
 <span style="color: maroon;">
  <code>
   <filepath>
   </filepath>
  </code>
 </span>
 is an absolute or relative path to the file.
 <br/>
 <br/>
 To run an unbuilt version, you must have installed:
 <br/>
 <ul>
  <li>
   wxPython
   <span style="color: maroon;">
    <code>
     ($ pip install -U wxPython)
    </code>
   </span>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <br/>
 <ul>
  <li>
   beautifulSoup
   <span style="color: maroon;">
    <code>
     ($ pip install beautifulsoup4)
    </code>
   </span>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <br/>
 <ul>
  <li>
   <a href="https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.5/python-3.6.5.exe" style="color:maroon;" target="_blank">
    python 3.6+
   </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <br/>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to find and then style certain words containing the `match` character in the HTML, you can create a decorator and use `re`:

```
import re

def apply_span(character, span_class='styling_default'):
  def outer(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
      html = f(*args, **kwargs)
      groups = map(str.split, re.findall(r'(?<=\b\w{1}\>)[\w\W]+(?=\</\w{1}\b)|(?<=\b\w{2}\>)[\w\W]+(?=\</\w{2}\b)', html))
      return re.sub(r'(?<=\b\w{1}\>)[\w\W]+(?=\</\w{1}\b)|(?<=\b\w{2}\>)[\w\W]+(?=\</\w{2}\b)', '{}', html).format(*[' '.join('<span class="{}">{}</span>'.format(span_class, i) if character in i else i for i in b) for b in groups])
    return wrapper
  return outer

@apply_span('h')
def return_html(*args, **kwargs):
   html = """
    <html>
      <h1>hello world</h1>
       <p>This is text to display</p>
   </html>
   """
   return html

print(return_html())
```

Output:

```
<html>
   <h1><span class="styling_default">hello</span> world</h1>
   <p><span class="styling_default">This</span> is text to display</p>
</html>
```

The goal of `span_class` is so that in your HTML, you can apply a `css` styling class later:

```
.span_class{
  color:red;
  font-size:20px;

}
```

Comment: thanks so much, is there a way that I can replace the HTML in tripple quotes with my own HTML?.

Comment: @JacobSchneider Glad to help! You can return any HTML in `return_html`. For instance, you can read from a file: `return open('filename.html').read()`, or provide your own in triple quotes.

Comment: I added a yellow background to the span tags, and it colors the whole HTML yellow. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @JacobSchneider Can you post your HTML?

Comment: I have the HTML that i want to highlight, but this is a file that a user will provide.